# Windows Virtualbox Guest Centos 7 This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

In windows 10, inside Virtualbox running centos 7 when I try to run the `docker-machine` command, it gives the below error

```
 docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox vbox-test
 Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

My computer has Virtualization enabled. How can I enable this in Virtualbox?

From windows I see Virtualization enabled.

```
wmic cpu get VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled
VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled
TRUE
```

Comment: to be clear: your host is win10, your guest is centos7, and you're trying to run `docker-machine create` on the guest?  virtualbox doesn't support virtual VT-x (there's a [feature request for it](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)).

Comment: As pointed out, VituralBox doesn't supported nested virtualization, which is required for Docker to function.  If you have Windows 10 Professional, Hyper-V supports, nested virtualization

Comment: Yes, Centos guest os inside the vituralbox. @Ramhound thanks for the pointer looks like now I need use doocktool box to try docker-machine. thanks for the information.

Comment: please format your question clearly next time